# Concrete5 Custom Tables Display Data

Tags: php, database, concrete5

I have a C# programming and WordPress background, but have been unable to get the latest version of WP to accomplish what I need to do. Because of this, I have turned to Concrete5 (version 8.5.4).
I have three custom tables that have been imported into the Concrete5 MySQL database. Now I want to search for partial name or city/state or region/state. The PHP code is already created, all I need to do is create the search and display page using Concrete5.
Because Concrete5 support and tutorials are not as prevalent as those for WP, I am coming up empty in this attempt. Any resource suggestions for developing a search and display page for data residing in custom tables?

Comment: If you want to assign data to pages, you should use the attribute system. With this system you are able to make searches with the `Concrete\Core\Page\PageList` object.

Comment: To answer your question it's important to know about the three custom tables you have. What’s they are? And is it something that you want to search from these?
If so, you might consider using Express. https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/express/overview